# How can I make a inner-div fixed on the bottom of outer-div, so it moves when the outer-div expands

Tags: html, css

So I have a inner-div inside an outer-div. I want the inner div to function as a footer, so it has to stick to the bottom of the outer-div. When the outer-div expands (in height), I want the footer to move along with the bottom of the outer-div.
I hope you understand what I mean?

How can I do this?

Comment: Other than just `<div>outer<div>inner</div></div>`?  `div`s are block level and will always be 100% in width unless you override or float or whatever; or by length, do you mean height?

Comment: Yes, I mean height, sorry

Comment: There's a couple different ways to do this depending on the structure of your page. A google search brings up lots of different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle [Fiddley de fiddly da](http://jsfiddle.net/u9ywe860/1/)

What you want is:

```
#inner {
    position:relative;
    top: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#outer {
    width:200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Hope it helps. May the code be with you.

Comment: @Persijn the top: 80% seems like it's an arbitrary value. How would you know what to set that to?

Comment: Wel you set it to the leftover from the width. So if width is 15% the top needs to be 85%. And if width 30% top is 70%. The reason you set it, is because it can to beyond the containing div.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fdus48df/

```
#inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
#outer {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

<button id="larger">Larger</button>
<button id="smaller">Smaller</button>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        height = 200;
        $('#larger').click(function() {
            height += 10;
            $('#outer').css('height',height+'px');
        });
        $('#smaller').click(function() {
            height -= 10;
            $('#outer').css('height',height+'px');
        });
    });
</script>
```